ONVIF Camera Control , Active Silicon 40x IP Camera. Pyhton Example not running
I have recently bought an Active Silicon Harrier 40x IP camera.On the manufacterur's website an example has been provide for demo testing the camera controls.
The example contains an C# projejct and a python script.The issue here is that the C# example runs fine and does what's described,but the python script file returns an error that is:

[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/wsdl\devicemgmt-10.wsdl'

I have installed the relevant libraries.
# Simple example showing how to send and receive VISCA commands 
# to the HArrier IP.
# To install Valkka: https://valkka.readthedocs.io/en/latest/requirements.html

from valkka.onvif import OnVif, DeviceManagement
import time   

IP = "10.10.10.102"
PORT=8000

# The deviceio.wsdl included in Valkka is missing the 'Token' element 
# for SendReceiveSerialCommand(). 
# The class below uses https://www.onvif.org/ver10/deviceio.wsdl,
# which is correct.
class MyDeviceIO(OnVif):
    wsdl_file = "https://www.onvif.org/ver10/deviceio.wsdl"
    namespace = "http://www.onvif.org/ver10/deviceIO/wsdl"
    sub_xaddr = "DeviceIO"
    port      = "DeviceIOBinding"

if __name__ == '__main__':
   try:
      device_service = DeviceManagement(
      ip=IP,
      port=PORT,
      user="",
      password=""
      )

      deviceIO_service = MyDeviceIO(
        ip=IP,
        port=PORT,
        user="",
        password=""
      )

      deviceio_type_factory = deviceIO_service.zeep_client.type_factory("http://www.onvif.org/ver10/deviceIO/wsdl")

      ports = deviceIO_service.ws_client.GetSerialPorts()
      serial_token = ports[0].token

      zoom_tele = bytes.fromhex('81 01 04 07 02 FF')
      zoom_wide = bytes.fromhex('81 01 04 07 03 FF')

      print("Send zoom tele command")
      serial_data = deviceio_type_factory.SerialData(Binary=zoom_tele)
      resp = deviceIO_service.ws_client.SendReceiveSerialCommand(Token=serial_token, SerialData=serial_data, TimeOut='PT0M6S', DataLength='100', Delimiter='')
      print("Camera response: " + resp['Binary'].hex())

      time.sleep(3)

      print("Send zoom wide command")
      serial_data = deviceio_type_factory.SerialData(Binary=zoom_wide)
      resp = deviceIO_service.ws_client.SendReceiveSerialCommand(Token=serial_token, SerialData=serial_data, TimeOut='PT0M6S', DataLength='100', Delimiter='')
      print("Camera response: " + resp['Binary'].hex())

   except Exception as e:
      print(e)

I tried running the pyhton script and got the error told above.I have to integrate the camera control in my main pyhton gui, for which I atleast need to get this example running.

Have you found a solution for this issue? When I contacted technical support via email, they informed me that the ONVIF Device Manager is used to check if the Zoom function is working with this application. You can find the ONVIF Device Manager here
I am using the Harrier 23x AF-Zoom IP 4K Camera and They mentioned that the above code does not work for this camera.

This looks like an issue with your Valkka install. Valkka uses zeep instally to consume the devicemgmt-10.wsdl file. The problem is not in the code you posted.
